# django group by in template

Tags: django, group-by

I am trying to record the history of records changes for my users. 
I 've got an history model :

```
class History(models.Model):
concerning      = models.ForeignKey(User)
field           = models.CharField(max_length=30)
creation_date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
author          = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='autor_history_info')
action          = models.CharField(max_length=30)
new_value       = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

and a history view :

```
def get_history(request):
changes = History.objects.all().filter(concerning=request.user).order_by('field')

return render(request, "get_history.html", {"changes" : changes)
```

and an history template :

```
{%for change in changes %}
  <h1>{{change.field}} </h1>
  {{change.creation_date}} 
  {{change.author}}
  {{change.action}}
  to
  {{change.new_value}}
  <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I unfortunately can't find the good way to make a group by that would limit to have one time the field displayed, and then all the changes below. How to make a group by to do so ?

Comment: please explain what field you are hoping to group by? or post some sample output the way you'd like it to look.

Comment: This is exactly the case the `regroup` built in filter is for. Check out the docs, it's on the complicated side but it works well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup . Or maybe `ifchanged` would do everything you need, that one's simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for change in changes %}

  {% ifchanged %}<h1>{{change.field}}</h1>{% endifchanged %}

  {{change.creation_date}} 
  {{change.author}}
  {{change.action}}
  to
  {{change.new_value}}
  <br>

{% endfor %}
```